# How do I setup a network that would allow both wired and wireless clients to go through a proxy first?

Tags: routing, router

In my current setup, I have a NETGEAR Wiressless-N Gigabit **router** WNR3500NL and a 3COM 10/100 24-pt **switch**.

The router has 5 ports, a single Internet port(yellow) followed by 4 Ethernet ports(orange)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TFrF.png

The Internet port(yellow) is connected directly to the Internet, the first Ethernet port is used to connect to a printer, the second Ethernet port is used to connect to an external desktop PC, the third Ethernet port is connected to the switch.

On the switch, the first port is connected to the router, as explained above, while the remaining ports are hooked up by several Ethernet cables.

For example, on my wired desktop. It will go through the following connection.

```
<<My PC>> -> <<Switch>> -> <<Router>>
```

As of now, the switch won't make any difference because port redirection works fine out of the box even with the switch in place.

As for wireless users, they would just connect to the router wirelessly via the SSID.

So the question is, I would like to setup a proxy on the external desktop PC that is connected to the router and force both wired/wireless users to go through a proxy first, instead of being able to access the Internet directly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you had to edit the access-lists on your router. add the external PCs IP to allow http,https,dns,ftp, ... remove the internal PCs IPs or Subnet and the wireless IPs/Subnet from the ACL -> they will be denied by the router and so unable to access the internet. Configure the proxy IP in your clients browser.
Are the Printer, the external PC and the internal PCs in the same IP Subnet? If so than they are all on the same network and you do not have an external pc and you also can patch all of them on the switch. but it doenst matter for the above config it will work too.